# Links from Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode, export-to-word

I kind of have a problem.

Maybe I'm doing the hardest way, I do not really know, if you could I'll appreciate for your help.

I upload photo to FTP and URL was upload to mysql in this format (http://*/claim/img/box.png, http://*/claim/img/box.png) with specific ID

```
----------------------------------- 
ID  -  URL 
1   -  http://*/claim/img/box.png, http://*/claim/img/box.png

-----------------------------------
```

And later I grab this data, and to generated form by ID.
I used explode to divide URL. And with FOR loop, I would display it perefctly, But here is the glitch. Because there is need to make export this form as a doc file and send email with this generated form. I can't end echo.
Because when I do only first part is send, but not images from array. 
For example:

```
$email = "ID 1<br>(Its the start of the form)";  
$photos = explode(',',    $claim['photos_url']); $arrlength = count($photos);   
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)   {   
echo "<img    src=".$photos[$x]."><br>";   } 
echo "The end of form";
```

I similar cases I simply use `echo "the start of text".$date."the end";`
But now, I have no idea how to do it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You mean from the loop only one image is being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks so incomplete , but i think you have an array some how that includes image urls
and you want to echo each one of them :

```
$images = array("http://127.0.0.1/img/1.jpg","http://127.0.0.1/img/2.jpg","http://127.0.0.1/img/3.jpg");

foreach($images as $image) 
{
echo "<img src='".$image."' />";
}
```

im not sure if i understand u correctly but hope it helps...